# PHP str_ireplace only once

Tags: php, regex, string

I'm looking for a modified version of str_ireplace (case-insensitive) that would replace ONLY ONCE.

I read online it's doable with preg or other techniques but I'm looking for a generic function I can re-use.

Bonus: the use will be to add a link anchor tag around the word, so it would be nice if it could somehow keep the capitalization of the original word.

Comment: what makes you unable to wrap preg_replace info user-defined function which you can re-use?

Comment: my answer was wrong, sorry for it, removed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you definitely want `preg_replace()`. If you would like you can create a user defined function:

```
function put_in_link($str)
{
    return preg_replace('/(linkText)/i', '<a href="/linkHref">$1</a>', $str, 1);
}
```

but there is kind of no reason to do this rather than `preg_replace()`. This call is really no more complex than a `str_ireplace()` call.

The last parameter was added for limiting to 1 occurrence.

Comment: is preg_replace slower than str_ireplace?

Comment: Also I assume you forgot the ",1" as the last parameter for limit

Comment: str_replace should usually be faster than preg_replace (no regex is being processed)

Comment: Because after writing the new code the page took forever to load - but maybe it was unrelated, I suspect Hurricane Irene hit some networks around my server.

Comment: @nute yes, it's indeed unrelated. preg_replace being used in hundreds of thousands scripts and works fine and fast. I don't see why it may fail you personally

Comment: I have it in a loop that iterates about 100 times - no big deal right?

Comment: SpeedTest.net is not accessible either, so it's probably something out of my hands. Maybe a backbone got affected by the hurricane.

Comment: @nute thanks for adding that `, 1` I'm a fool for forgetting it! Yes `preg_replace` is slower but only by a tiny amount, especially with a simple pattern like this one. Even looping a thousand times is time trivial on shared hosting (which has lower resources available than your laptop).

Answer (score 0):

PHP is a programming lanugage. Use it like a tool. E.g. the functions that ship with PHP do not cover all of your bases. However, you can combine existing functions into a new function. That works pretty well.

The bottom line is, that you write yourself a function that has the missing functionality (you can change the inner of the function later you only need to take care it behaves exactly as earlier).

This is an example function actually doing what you're looking for by using `stripos` and `substr_replace` ([Demo](http://codepad.org/qCuiTvN9)):

```
function str_ireplace_once($search, $replace, $subject, &$count = 0)
{
    $pos = stripos($subject, $search);
    if (false === $pos)
        return $subject;

    $count = 1;
    return substr_replace($subject, $replace, $pos, strlen($search));
}
```

And don't make any assumptions about speed unless it's *really* an issue for you. But stop guessing around whether it is or not. Solve your problems first, don't create additional ones out of the blue.

Answer (score 0):

```
$text;
$word;
$replacement;
$text = substr_replace(
            $text, 
            $replacement,
            stripos($text, $word),
            strlen($word));
```

Should work

http://ideone.com/iIKbV